# Ubuntu's Screen Problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, browser

I am a newcomer to Linux. I have Dual Booted my Ubuntu with Windows. But when I am using it I am seeing this kind of problem with some third-party applications, such as Firefox, Chrome, VS Code, and some other third-party software also. Like these photos.
[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

The display is looking like corrupted. I tried to reinstall but the problem was not fixed. And I haven't installed spam applications. The screenshots were taken after a fresh installation. I tried this with Linux mint also and I can see the same problem in that too. I have used Ubuntu in the VirtualBox there were no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these problems in Ubuntu are caused by some issue with graphics driver or configuration. While installing, at the start Ubuntu does provide you an option to install third party graphics driver with just a check.

This issue can be resolved by installing the compatible drivers again.

Refer to this link to install Nvidia graphics driver:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

This link is just for reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-problems-graphics.html.en

If nothing works, you can always reinstall Ubuntu.