# DIsplay problem with ubuntu 22.04 on Virtualbox

Tags: drivers, graphics, virtualbox, 22.04

Recently I created Ubuntu virtual machine. The problem is that, there is a problem with display. There are blurred part when I open almost all of installed software. I have already followed some solution proposed by [this threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system)  and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285300/ubuntus-screen-problem#:%7E:text=Most%20of%20the%20time%20these,installing%20the%20compatible%20drivers%20again.) but it was not helpful for me.

My problem is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285300/ubuntus-screen-problem#:%7E:text=Most%20of%20the%20time%20these,installing%20the%20compatible%20drivers%20again.) but with different Ubuntu version.

Here are my config:

- Physical configuration:

  - Laptop mark : Dell core i5 10th generation
  - Graphic : Intel iris Xe
- Software configuration

  - Architecture : Virtual Machine
  - Host system : Windows 10
  - Virtual system : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Here is the Print Screen for the problem. I should mark in re

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are using Virtual Box, you should install ***Guest  Additions*** to you Ubuntu Virtual Machine: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: I already installed the Guest Addition, and I've just re-do the installation to make sure it is correctly installed but the display problem is still there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Guest Additions. This is a problem with 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by unchecking the option **Enable 3D Acceleration**. I mean, the 3D Acceleration should be desabled to solve the issue.

[image: How to desable 3D Acceleration]